# How to read info from a binary data file into an array of structures C++

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I am a beginning C++ student. I have a structure array that holds employee info.
I can put values into the structure, write those values to a binary dat file and 
read the values back into the program so that it can be displayed to the console.
Here is my problem.  Once I close the program, I can't get the file to read the data from the file back into memory - instead it reads "garbage."

I tried a few things and then read this in my book:

> **NOTE**: Structures containing pointers cannot be correctly stored to
>   disk using the techniques of this section.  This is because if the
>   structure is read into memory on a subsequent run of the program, it
>   cannot be guaranteed that all program variables will be at the same
>   memory locations.

I am pretty sure this is what is going on when I try to open a .dat file with previously stored information and try to read it into a structure array.

I can send my code examples if that would help clarify my question.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: We would need to see your actual code to determine the problem.

Comment: Keep reading the book.  In all likelihood, the answer will be in the next section.

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant: That tag has been deprecated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Speaking generally (since I don't have your code) there's two reasons you generally shouldn't just write the bytes of a struct or class to a file:

- As your book mentioned, writing a pointer to disk is pointless, since you're just storing a random address and not the data at that address. You need to write out the data itself.
- You *especially* should not attempt to write a struct/class all at once with something like
  `fwrite(file, myStruct, sizeof(myStruct))`. Compilers sometimes put empty bytes between variables in structs in order to let the processor read them faster - this is called [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_padding). Using a different compiler or compiling for a different computer architecture can pad structures differently, so a file that opens correctly on one computer might not open correctly on another.

There's lots of ways you can write out data to a file, be it in a binary format or in some human-readable format like XML. Regardless of what method you choose to use (each has strengths and weaknesses), every one of them involves writing each piece of data you care to save one by one, then reading them back in one by one. Higher level languages like Java or C# have ways to do this automagically by storing metadata about objects, but this comes at the cost of more memory usage and slower program execution.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone! I did get it to work the next day. Next time I will include the code with the question.